# WCF/REST hash/salt datamember field

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, rest, authentication

I have a datacontract and in my service I am trying to hash/salt the password datamember:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, _passwordSalt); //invalid expression? _passwordSalt?
        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where have you defined the variable `_passwordSalt`?

Comment: I know just need a little help on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `_passwordSalt` with this function `GenerateSalt()` from one of my projects:

```
protected RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public byte[] GenerateSalt() {
    byte[] salt = new byte[10];
    random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}
```

By the way you have to save this generated salt. You need the same salt every time to check the password.